# No output with v.net.connect in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, grass-7.0

[image: Example]

I am using grass algorithm  `v.net.connect` of the processing toolbox. It runs but does not produce any output. I don't know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: [2019-04-12 16:52:04] processing.runalg("grass7:v.net.components","C:/Users/khalids/Downloads/Jumeirah-Mina-A'Salam-Floor5-paths.geojson",0,None,None,True,"55.1851911253,55.1863236978,25.1345230427,25.1360458081",-1,0.0001,None,None)[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dk4X.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dk4X.png) can you explain what the issue is why I am not able to see the output for v.net.components

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/160662)

Answer (score 1):

Bring up your "History" window under the processing menu (top menu), expand your ALGORITHM folder and look for the process you just ran.  Double click and it will bring up an additional information window that should list any errors encountered while running the request.  I keep getting an error: "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal"  From what I can see, all needed variables and an ending ") are not being added correctly when I use the ui to run the algorithm.  I've been looking at the Python console functionality in QGIS, so we'll see.  I am also updating my QGIS.  I hope the History files help you, as they will at least give you some information about why nothing is happening after you attempt to run a tool.